# Populating the Values stored in one file and using them in other file

Tags: batch-file

I Have 2 variables in common for 20 batch files, so i want to store these 2 variables into one file and then populate them into the batch files whichever uses these 2 variables. Can some one please assist me the code for this.

Requirement :

Variables to be stored in one file:

```
DBNAME:PROD
REGION:ABC
```

Now these two variables needs to be picked from here and populated into other batch files where they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the format: store the lines in the form of variable assignment *commands*, i.e. as a batch file:

```
SET DBNAME=PROD
SET REGION=ABC
```

That way you would be able to simply *call* that batch file from any other batch file that needs those variables. Assuming the above is saved as `myvars.bat`, you would go like this:

```
...
CALL myvars.bat
:: proceed with using the variables
...
```